# Is there anyway to delete a Details View Row?

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I am trying to delete a details view row. I do not want the "information row" at the side. For example, if I am trying to show a product name, i would rather have "Special China Teapot" as a standalone rather than "Product Name:" then followed by another row saying "Special China Teapot". Does anyone know how to erase the side row?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying, but you can set the Visible-property of the row to false.

```
yourGrid.Rows[rownumber].Visible = false;
```